# How do I find the 3d indices of where one array is larger than another in R (in order to replace these elements with NaN)?

Tags: r, indexing

I want to find the indices where elements in one matrix are larger than another.
Here's my reproducible example:

```
#create the two arrays
array1<-array(1:100,c(512,256,12))
array2<-array(1:200,c(512,256,12))
#Find where array2 is greater than array1
idxs<-which(array2 > array1)
```

This returns a vector of integers which are the indices for what I want (except they are not 3d.ie. i,j,k indices).
What I want are indices across the 3 dimensions of the array, to tell me exactly where the entries that are greater occur. So for example, if it only occurred once at the very first entry of the array, I would be returned [1 1 1].

Ultimately, I want to replace all the instances where the elements are larger with a NaN. Perhaps I don't even need the 3d indices to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `arr.ind` option of `which`:

```
which(array2 > array1, arr.ind = TRUE)
```